# Query data from multiple arrays

Tags: algorithm

I have arrays like:

**[** 1,2,3,4,5,6 **]**

**[** 11,22,33 **]**

**[** 62,63,64,65,66,67 **]**

I need to get data from these different length arrays with pagination, for example, giving the page size 5, the pages of results should be:
**[** 1,11,62,2,22 **],** **[** 63,3,33,64,4 **],** **[** 65, 5, 66, 6, 67 **]**

That is to say I sort data based on the index of data in arrays, and the count of arrays is not limit to 3.

My clumsy solution is to traverse all the arrays and combine them into a new array, which is not effective. Is there better and effective algorithm to get the page data without combination/union. Like giving the page 2, I can get the start index, and the end index, to get data directly. Thanks in advance！

---

### | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |

### |11|22|33|

### |62|63|64|65|66|67|

Thanks a lot, @Aristide! This helps me a lot. Actually, my arrays are very large arrays, so the better solution is to get the giving page data result directly. Like giving the page 2, is there a way to get the elements on page 2, not counting the first page elements one by one util to get the 2nd page.

Thanks, @Aristide! According to my description above, may mislead readers. My input arrays

---

### | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |

### |11|22|33|

### |62|63|64|65|66|67|

giving the page 2, return the page 2 elements directly avoiding counting the first page elements one by one! So the result/output should be:**[** 63,3,33,64,4 **]**

Comment: Is your expected result correct? You have not considered `4` in your answer. I think this must be correct answer `[1, 11, 62, 2, 22], [63, 3, 33, 64, 4], [65, 5, 66, 6, 67]`

Comment: @HarshGupta Thanks, my carelessness, my result is not correct, I repost my question.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 2.7 with `itertools`, direct access to the `page_index` page (starting from zero):

```
 import itertools

 def select_page(data, page_size, page_index):

     def element_generator(x, y):
         empty_row_count = 0
         while empty_row_count < len(data):
             if x < len(data[y]):
                 yield data[y][x]
                 empty_row_count = 0
             else:
                 empty_row_count += 1
             y += 1
             if y == len(data):
                 y = 0
                 x += 1

     # initialize the generator at the minimal possible coordinates
     (x, y) = divmod(page_size * page_index, len(data))
     elements = element_generator(x, y)

     # drop as many elements than the number of gaps
     for row in data:
         list(itertools.islice(elements, max(0, x-len(row))))

     # return the page_size next elements
     return list(itertools.islice(elements, page_size))
```

Some tests, input:

```
 data = [
     [  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6 ],
     [ 11, 22, 33             ],
     [ 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67 ],
 ]
 page_size = 5

 for page_index in range(5):
     print select_page(data, page_size, page_index)
```

Output:

```
[1, 11, 62, 2, 22]
[63, 3, 33, 64, 4]
[65, 5, 66, 6, 67]
[]
[]
```

Comment: Thanks @Aristide! This helps me a lot. I want to get the data directly on the 2nd page, just like the detail I added to my post.  Maybe this is a little greedy, the algorithm is really my short!

Comment: OK, I understand now. May be you should give an example of your function input / output. Given your arrays and the index 2, you expect [ 63,3,33,64,4 ], right? I thought your expected output was the big list of pages :-)

Comment: Never mind. Both problems are quite interesting. I've deleted my solutions to the first one, and replaced them with something which should be more applicable to your use case. More pythonic though (I have used generators to make the code prettier).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Aristide. That's the one I want. For me that's really a challenge.

Comment: 好亲切，看到中文了，谢谢你， @Aristide！